# Convert GLSL functions to Metal

Tags: c++, glsl, metal

I came across [this site](http://mercury.sexy/hg_sdf/) and start studying SDF for a while now. However I still don't quite get the idea behind this code:

```
float pMod1(inout float p, float size) {
    float halfsize = size*0.5;
    float c = floor((p + halfsize)/size);
    p = mod(p + halfsize, size) - halfsize;
    return c;
}
```

I convert it to my `Metal` code:

```
#define _inout(T) T
...
float pMod1(_inout (float) p, float size) {
    float halfsize = size*0.5;
    float c = floor((p + halfsize)/size);
    p = mod(p + halfsize, size) - halfsize;
    return c;
}
```

but not getting the expected result. However, if I change to

```
#define _inout(T) T
...
float pMod1(_inout (float) p, float size) {
    float halfsize = size*0.5;
    float c = floor((p + halfsize)/size);
    p = mod(p + halfsize, size) - halfsize;
    return p; // <-- change from c to p
}
```

Then I get what I expected.

1. I suspect my way of converting `inout` is not entirely correct. I borrowed it from some `Shadertoy` code, but I am not convince it really work that way.
2. How is `c` useful? in the code from the side it comment:

> Many of the operators partition space into cells. An identifier
>   or cell index is returned, if possible. This return value is 
>   intended to be optionally used e.g. as a random seed to change 
>   parameters of the distance functions inside the cells.

I don't understand what it really mean. Can someone suggest some examples how to use the cell index?

**Update1:**

I change the code to:

```
float pMod1(thread float &p, float size) {
    float halfsize = size*0.5;
    float c = floor((p + halfsize)/size);
    p = mod(p + halfsize, size) - halfsize;
    return c;
}
```

and now I get another error message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

from this line:

```
command_encoder.setComputePipelineState(cps)
```

Here is the whole code from MetaView.swift:

```
import MetalKit

public class MetalView: MTKView, NSWindowDelegate {

    var queue: MTLCommandQueue! = nil
    var cps: MTLComputePipelineState! = nil

    var timer: Float = 0
    var timerBuffer: MTLBuffer!

    var mousexBuffer: MTLBuffer!
    var mouseyBuffer: MTLBuffer!
    var pos: NSPoint!
    var floatx: Float!
    var floaty: Float!

    required public init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.framebufferOnly = false
        device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        registerShaders()
    }


    override public func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
        if let drawable = currentDrawable {
            let command_buffer = queue.commandBuffer()
            let command_encoder = command_buffer.computeCommandEncoder()
            command_encoder.setComputePipelineState(cps) ///////<-- This line throw an error.
            command_encoder.setTexture(drawable.texture, atIndex: 0)
            command_encoder.setBuffer(timerBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 1)
            command_encoder.setBuffer(mousexBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 2)
            command_encoder.setBuffer(mouseyBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 3)
            update()
            let threadGroupCount = MTLSizeMake(8, 8, 1)
            let threadGroups = MTLSizeMake(drawable.texture.width / threadGroupCount.width, drawable.texture.height / threadGroupCount.height, 1)
            command_encoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadGroups, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadGroupCount)
            command_encoder.endEncoding()
            command_buffer.presentDrawable(drawable)
            command_buffer.commit()
        }
    }

    func registerShaders() {
        queue = device!.newCommandQueue()
        do {
            let library = device!.newDefaultLibrary()!
            let kernel = library.newFunctionWithName("compute")!
            timerBuffer = device!.newBufferWithLength(sizeof(Float), options: [])
            mousexBuffer = device!.newBufferWithLength(sizeof(Float), options: [])
            mouseyBuffer = device!.newBufferWithLength(sizeof(Float), options: [])
            cps = try device!.newComputePipelineStateWithFunction(kernel)
        } catch let e {
            Swift.print("\(e)")
        }
    }

    func update() {
        timer += 0.01
        var bufferPointer = timerBuffer.contents()
        memcpy(bufferPointer, &timer, sizeof(Float))
        bufferPointer = mousexBuffer.contents()
        memcpy(bufferPointer, &floatx, sizeof(NSPoint))
        bufferPointer = mouseyBuffer.contents()
        memcpy(bufferPointer, &floaty, sizeof(NSPoint))
    }

    override public func mouseDragged(event: NSEvent) {
        pos = convertPointToLayer(convertPoint(event.locationInWindow, fromView: nil))
        let scale = layer!.contentsScale
        pos.x *= scale
        pos.y *= scale
        floatx = Float(pos.x)
        floaty = Float(pos.y)
        debugPrint("Hello",pos.x,pos.y)
    }
}
```

**Update2:**
I suspect the error in **Update1** is because of the way I split the `Metal` files. So I simplify it by copy all the functions into 1 `Metal` file and now I produce new error:

```
float pMod1(thread float &p, float size) {
    float halfsize = size*0.5;
    float c = floor((p + halfsize)/size);
    p = mod(p + halfsize, size) - halfsize;
    return c;
}

static float map( float3 p )
{
    float size = 10.0;

    p.x = pMod1(p.x,size);/////<--- this produce the error.

    float box = fBox(p, float3(1));
    float sphere = length(p - float3(1)) - 1;
    float d = min(box,sphere);

    float guard = -fBoxCheap(p, float3(size*0.5));
    guard = abs(guard) + size*0.1;

    return min(d,guard);
}
```

Error:

> Call to `pMod1` is ambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent function in Metal is

```
float pMod1(thread float &p, float size) {
    float halfsize = size*0.5;
    float c = floor((p + halfsize)/size);
    p = mod(p + halfsize, size) - halfsize;
    return c;
}
```

In order to modify a parameter, you need to pass it by reference, just as in C++. In Metal, you also need to explicitly qualify it as being in the `thread` address space (as opposed to `constant`, `threadgroup`, etc.)

The purpose of the `pMod` family of functions in hg_sdf is to "fold" space, allowing you create duplicates of objects that repeat at regular intervals. The `c` value is like an object index, indicating which "partition" of folded space the object resides in. You can ignore it unless you're adjusting object appearance (by applying a different material or adding surface detail, etc.)

This is all described pretty thoroughly in [Johann Körndorfer's talk here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8nFqwOho-s).

**Update**

In order to call the function, you need to create a temporary variable to store the swizzled-out component you want to modify, since you can't pass swizzled vector components by reference in Metal.

```
float px = p.x;
float c = pMod1(px, size);
p.x = px;
```

Since `px` was passed by reference, `p.x` now contains the value that was written to `px` inside `pMod1`.

Comment: I changed as per your advise but have new error. Please check my **Update1** with all the details.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't pass swizzled vector components by reference. You'll need to copy `p.x` into a local variable, pass _that_ into the function, then assign it _back_ to `p.x` after the function call. Also, don't assign the result of the function to `p.x`; the return value is the cell index and is completely different from the value you want returned in the reference parameter.

Comment: How can I use the value of `thread float &p` in the `pMod()` function since it return `c`? I check the video they are using the same function but somehow they got back the value `p`.

Comment: I've added an example call above that hopefully clarifies this a little.